# onClick Ajax data not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, isset

As i'm building an website that needs Ajax for sending POST methods without refreshing the entire page.

I tried using ajax to send data from an onclick event on an LINK-tag, but the ajax code does seem to send an EMPTY post.

This is the php/jquery/ajax code:

```
                <p id="school_content"> 
                </p>
                <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        $(document).ready(function() {
                            $(".toggleThis").click(function(){
                                var Id = $(this).attr('id');

                                $.ajax({
                                     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                     url: "id_script.php",
                                     type: "POST",
                                     data: {
                                            'school_name': Id,
                                         },
                                        success: function(data){
                                            alert(Id);
                                        },
                                    });

                                $("#school_content").load("id_script.php");
                            });
                        });
                    </script>
```

The LINK-tag has the 'id' of the school of wich the information needs to be shown in the PARAGRAPH with 'id' "school_content" by this jquery part: $("#school_content").load("id_script.php"); .

The var Id = $(this).attr('id'); part works, because he's giving me the right school_name in an alert(); if I ask it to.

The id_script.php needs to get this POST in the usual way, but is does not..

The id_script.php code:

```
<?php 
include('connect.php');
header('Content-Type: application/json');
if(isset($_POST['school_name'])){
        $Id = $_POST['school_name'];
        $extract = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM school_kaart WHERE school_name='$Id'");
        $numro=mysqli_num_rows($extract);
            if(mysqli_num_rows($extract) == '1'){   
                $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($extract);
                echo 'Yes it works!';
            }
            else{
                echo 'Nope, didnt work!';
            }
}
else{
        echo 'Not posted!';
}

?>
```

I'm still getting "Not posted!" in the PARAGRAPH I mentioned earlier. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: check your headers.  `Content-type` is the one you're probably missing.  Your PHP may not be expecting JSON data.

Answer (score 0):

`.load` is shorthand for an ajax request so you are actually doing 2 request. 
The latter isn't sending any data and so it returns 'Not Posted!';

http://api.jquery.com/load/

try

```
            <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function() {
                        $(".toggleThis").click(function(){
                            var Id = $(this).attr('id');

                            $.ajax({
                                 url: "id_script.php",
                                 type: "POST",
                                 data: {
                                        'school_name': Id,
                                     },
                                    success: function(data){
                                        alert(Id);
                                       $("#school_content").html(data);
                                    },
                                });


                              //remove this
                            //$("#school_content").load("id_script.php");
                        });
                    });
                </script>
```

Comment: @RikEckhardt remove `header('Content-Type: application/json');` because you're not actually sending json data.